# Loading fixtures for particular test cases

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

i have a situation where i need to load different fixtures for different cases in an functional test class

```
class Mytest(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['somefixture.json']

    def test_some_test_method(self):
        #load more fixtures for this test case
        fixtures.extend(['some_other_fixture.json'])
```

does django support this, how do i go about it?

Comment: do you think its worth it to write functional tests for django admin interface in my project?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.fixtures

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to use fixtures in a way that's not entirely advisable.

Fixtures are only meant to have data that's common across your entire test suite, and not at a class/testcase level.

Keeping your tests insulated from each other is incredibly important when you are trying to make a good test suite. Having tests altering each others data, or having tests that depend on another test altering data are inherently fragile.

You should be using setUp() and tearDown() to take care of class level data manipulation, coupled with correct class segregation in your functional suite.

On top of that, you can also look at this usage of tearDown(), the usage is different without the annotation:

```
@classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
```

Comment: Thank you, do you think its worth to write functional tests for the admin interface in my project or i should just assume that it work well and no need to write the tests???

Answer (score 0):

Your inclination to load different data for different tests is good.  However, as with many situations, fixtures are a primitive and violent tool for this task.

Instead, I suggest that you try a factory approach.  By creating factories for the models that you are using, you can achieve several wins in your scenario:

- Your test suite will maintain coherence even if your models change (though, if you add new required fields, you may need to update your factory, though this is still a far cry from having to create a new fixture)
- You can DRY up a lot of the logic involved in creating the proper state for each test by subtly changing the implementation of the factory to meet the requirements of each individual test
- You will ensure that your test is being run against data that can actually exist in that state of your app, rather than the state that the app was in when you created the fixture.

[Give Factory Boy a look.](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)